# A theorem about the criterion for existence of a Riemann integral

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-series, riemann-integration

I am looking for the proof of the following theorem. I can not prove it myself and also can't find any solutions on the internet. The theorem goes as follows:

Let $f:[a,b]\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. If $f(x+)$ and $f(x-)$ (left and right hand limits of x) exist for every $x\in(a,b)$ as well as $f(a+)$ and $f(b-)$ then f is bounded and Riemann integrable (Riemann integral exists and is a real number).

Note that I am looking for the solution  without use  of complex analysis.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > **Lemma 0.** Any infinite subset of a totally ordered set contains a strictly increasing sequence or a strictly decreasing sequence.

Proof:  Say $(x_n)$ is a sequence of distinct elements of some totally ordered set. Say $n$  is *dominant* if $x_n>x_k$ for all  $k>n$.

If there are infinitely many dominant values of $n$, say $n_1<n_2<\dots$, then $(x_{n_j})$ is strictly decreasing. Otoh if there are only finitely many dominant values of $n$ then there exists $N$ such that every $n>N$ is non-dominant, allowing you to construct a strictly increasing sequence $(x_{n_j})$.

Now say $f$ is as above, and define $$\omega(x)=\max(|f(x)-f(x+)|,|f(x)-f(x-)|).$$

> > **Lemma 1.** $f$ is bounded, and for every $\epsilon>0$ the set $\{x:\omega(x)>\epsilon\}$ is finite.

Proof. If $f$ is unbounded then there is a strictly monotone sequence $(x_n)$ such that $|f(x_n)|\to\infty$. If $x_n$ increases to $x$  then $f(x-)$ does not exist; similarly if $x_n$ decreases to  $x$.

Similarly if $(x_n)$ is a strictly monotone sequence  with $\omega(x_n)>\epsilon$.

> > **Cor.** $f$ is continuous at $x$ for all but countably many $x$ (so in particular $f$ is continuous almost everywhere, hence Riemann integrable).

You *can* find the theorem that a bounded almost-everywhere-continuous function is Riemann integrable [on the internet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_integral#Integrability).

Comment: Seems good, thank you.

Comment: Sir, can you please have a look at this question :  https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3380406/394202